# Passing an object with arrays as values for some keys to a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

So I am working with SQL server and the API is supposed call a stored procedure passing the following as parameter

```
{
   "Survey": "Satisfaction survey",
   "Questions" : [
      {
         "Question": "Are you satisfied with the customer service?",
         "Options" : [
              {
                  "Option" : "Yes"
              },
              {
                  "Option" : "No"
              },
              {
                  "Option" : "No comment"
              }
          ]    
      }
   ]
}
```

This is just a bare bones objects and there are many more keys. The database has tables called surveys, questions, and options. The keys need to be inserted in their respective tables. Is there a feasible way to pass the object as a parameter or should I modify the object to pass it as a parameter? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : the schema of the tables are as follows

Survey:

```
SurveyID | bigint  | primary key
Survey   | varchar |
```

Questions:

```
QuestionID | bigint  | primary key
Question   | varchar | 
SectionID  | bigint  | foreign key
```

Options :

```
OptionID    | bigint  | primary key
Option      | varchar | 
QuestionID  | bigint  | foreign key
```

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may pass this JSON content as an `nvarchar(max)` parameter and parse it with `OPENJSON()`. The statement depends on the structure of the tables (you may include this information in the question).

Comment: @Zhorov i have added the structure to the question. Is the approach you mentioned still valid. If so could you link some resources to the same

Comment: I am running on SQL server 2019

Comment: The proc is supposed to insert and I haven't figured out how to do the foreign key part yet to point to the parent question or survey.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using OPENJSON() as mentioned in @Zhorov 's first comment. It is giving me the needed results. I followed the following documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).